# Need some help installing Windows on SSD for the first time

Tags: windows-8, windows-10, ssd, windows-installation

I bought a 7-pin SATA cable will it work for a normal SSD (SanDisk Ultra II 240GB)
Do I perform a clean installation of Windows (I have win8 on my HDD and want to get 10 for SSD) or I clone it (and which program)? Both way works for me because I just bought this PC and has barely any space used but which way is better.

Do I need to format SSD prior installation? Just plug it in and update drivers for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I bought a 7-pin SATA cable will it work for a normal SSD (SanDisk
>   Ultra II 240GB)

Yes, most likely your computer will treat it like any other hard drive, if not try updating your bios

> Do I perform a clean installation of Windows (I have win8 on my HDD
>   and want to get 10 for SSD) or I clone it (and which program)?

Either one will work fine, there are tons of different pieces of software, personally I like [Macrium Reflect](http://www.macrium.com/reflectfree.aspx) but most software designed for this purpose will work fine. A clean install is always the better way to go if you can though.

> Do I need to format SSD prior installation?

No, the Windows installation program will, or the cloning software will.

> Just plug it in and update drivers for it?

Just plug it in, it doesn't use any different drivers than a standard hard drive.